# How can I download the source code of the gradle eclipse plugin?

Tags: gradle, eclipse-plugin, gradle-plugin

I need to download the source code of the plugin eclipse used in gradle, Is it possible because I searched and I didn’t found any source...

Comment: Thie Eclipse source is in Git at `git.eclipse.org`. You probably want the 'buildship' project.

Comment: In gradle there is an aclipse plugin, we apply it in the build.gradle : "apply plugin: 'eclipse' ", and we use  it to generate eclipse project files; I nned the source code of this plugin

Comment: The `eclipse` plugin is a part of Gradle and therefor its source code can be found in the [`ide` subproject of the Gradle GitHub repository](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/ide/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugins/ide/eclipse/EclipsePlugin.java).